# progress bar properties python2.72 pywinauto

Tags: progress-bar, python-2.7

I want to read the contents of a "msctls_progress32" in a window. I don't know how to access its content, as I don't know about the propeties. Like, textbox has text, and a label has a caption, how do I access the contents of the "msctls_progress32". I need to read the last line of the contents and then do some procession, like run another program, if the content now reads "Success". Following are the control identifiers. I'm using Python 2.72 with pywinauto.

```
app.Cm3wsd.print_control_identifiers() 
Control Identifiers: 
Button - '&Exit' (L766, T594, R819, B618) '&Exit' '&ExitButton' 'Button' 'Button0' 'Button1' 
Static - 'File to &download' (L459, T366, R537, B379) 'File to &download' 'File to &downloadStatic' 'Static' 
Edit - 'C:\Users\pvathark\Desktop\sampleABC123.hex' (L459, T384, R767, B407) 'Edit' 'File to &downloadEdit' 
Button - '&Browse...' (L768, T384, R821, B407) '&Browse...' '&Browse...Button' 'Button2' 
Button - '&Monitor Status' (L459, T415, R819, B578) '&Monitor Status' '&Monitor StatusGroupBox' 'GroupBox' 
ListBox - '' (L474, T439, R804, B553) 'File to &downloadListBox' 'ListBox' 
Button - '&Start' (L550, T594, R603, B618) '&Start' '&StartButton' 'Button3' 
Button - 'Run' (L694, T594, R747, B618) 'Button5' 'Run' 'RunButton'
```

**msctls_progress32 - 'Progress1' (L474, T561, R804, B569) '&Monitor StatusProgress' 'Progress'**

```
Button - '&Configure...' (L466, T594, R531, B617) '&Configure...' '&Configure...Button' 'Button6'
```

Regards, Vinu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, Windows Progress common control has the next additional methods:

```
GetPosition()
GetState()
GetStep()
SetPosition(pos)
StepIt()
```

If you need a text, use the following construction:

```
window['Progress1'].Texts()
```

Also, you can easily view the properties and methods available through a GUI tool for pywinauto.